# How to search by integer type column using morphia, mongodb, play framework

Tags: mongodb, playframework, mapping, morphia

HI I have following data items in mongo db

{ "id" : 950,  "name" : "Name 1" },
{ "id" : 951,  "name" : "name 2" }

I have tried mapping id as both Integer and String.

and I used morphia + play to connect mongodb and used DAO of morphia.
I need to do a search by id like (in sql **where id like '95%'** ) and get the result as list.

List pList =  ds.createQuery(Person.class).field(**"id"**).startsWith(**"95"**).asList();  // this is not working 
Any ideas how get this done ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having already answered on the play mailing list and the morphia list, i'll answer here so others will see it, too.  startsWith() is a text based operation.  It doesn't work against numbers.  you'll have to use a greaterThan/lessThan query for range checking.